# PostGIS checking if a circle contains a certain point

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have `Fighter`s and `Arena`s. Each of the objects has its own geolocation represented by a pair of values: `(lat, long)`, each `Fighter` has also `searchDistance`, that's, a search radius. I need to output arenas available to each fighter, that's to say, those arenas that are located within the fighter's search distance.

The PostGIS documentation looks somewhat cryptic to me, too many terms that I don't understand.
Seems like I need to go with `ST_DWithin` but I don't get how exactly and what values should be passed this function.

The function is supposed to be like this:

```
public async isArenaAvailableToFighter(fighterId: number, arenaId: number): Promise<boolean> {
    // 1. Retrieve (long, lat) for the arena and (long, lat, searchDistance) for the fighter;
    // 2. Using PostGIS check if the arena is within the fighters search radius;
    //    return TRUE if it is and return FALSE if it is not;
    return;
}
```

My problem is with the second step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be as simple as

```
WHERE ST_DWithin(player, arena, radius)
```

If you want to use geometrical functions, it would be much smarter to store the location as a point than as a pair of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you! But if you don't mind my asking, what exactly are those `player` and `arena` params? According to the official doc, `ST_DWithin(geography gg1, geography gg2, double precision distance_meters, boolean use_spheroid = true);` From the description of geometry type I understand these are pairs (lat, long), but in which order then? (lat, long) or (long, lat)? Sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: Also, how does it understand that the radius is related to , let's say, the player and not to the arena?

Comment: `player` and `arena` are `geometry`s. You can construct them from the coordinates or (perferably) already store them as `geometry` in the database. `radius` is the distance: since distance is symmetrical, it does not make a difference if you measure from A to B or vice versa.

Comment: Okay. I run this `SELECT ST_DWithin(ST_GeometryFromText('Point(50.489013572184895 30.55156710143597)'), ST_GeometryFromText('Point(47.12662998867746 37.52039153868788)'), 100000)`, radius is in meters. And it returns `[ { st_dwithin: true } ]` even though the distance between those two points is ~632km which means it should be `false`. Why is it `true` then?

Comment: You didn't specify a SRID. If you use SRID 4326 (as I assume you intend), the unit would be degrees (look in `spatial_ref_sys`).

Comment: Yeah, I read the doc a little bit more thoroughly and ended up using geography instead of geometry, that's to say, I ran the following query: `SELECT ST_DWithin(ST_GeographyFromText('Point(30.55156710143597 50.489013572184895)'), ST_GeographyFromText('Point(30.95405991798564 50.366633785123376)'), 100000)` and everything worked the expected way. In the previous calculations I had also messed up the lat/long order, longitude should go first. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.